# No exception message supplied (Django REST POST)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.6 and Django REST Framework.

I have a very simple view. For demonstration purposes, I want it to return all users email addresses when it receives a GET request, and the same when it receives a POST request.

This is the code I am using:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from core import models

class ListUsers(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        usernames = [user.email for user in models.User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)

    def post(self, request):
        usernames = [user.email for user in models.User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)
```

When I do GET it works fine, however when I do POST I get this error:
`No exception message supplied`

I cannot figure out what the problem is, I have tried everything I can think of, I've scoured the Django REST Framework documentation and can't find anything.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Stack Trace as requested:
Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localdev:1989/api/rest/v1/register

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'core',
 'apiv1')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  59.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in render
  577.         context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in get_context
  554.             'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(view, 'POST', request),
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in get_rendered_html_form
  423.             data = request.DATA
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in DATA
  197.             self._load_data_and_files()
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in _load_data_and_files
  267.             self._data, self._files = self._parse()
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in _parse
  359.         parsed = parser.parse(stream, media_type, self.parser_context)
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/wedding/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/parsers.py" in parse
  63.             raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))

Exception Type: ParseError at /api/rest/v1/register
Exception Value:
```

I figured out that it is caused by incorrect JSON being submitted. For example if I have an extra comma. How can I make this return an error message as opposed to this 500 error?

**Update 2**
POST Data:

```
{
 "email": "my@email.com",
 "full_name": "mark winterbottom",
 "password": "2secure4u",
}
```

Comment: Provide the full stack trace please..

Comment: @mariodev I've added the strack trace. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you send the data from your client, so at least we can replicate the error..

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate the same error.. do you have some additional settings, what client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic error page, you should be able to set the [handler500 url handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view) in your *urls.py*. I also noticed you are not accepting the format kwarg for the `post` method. You might wanna add that in there.

Another possibility would be to override the [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method of the view class and catch the exception there, á la:

```
class ListUsers(APIView):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(ListUsers, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        except ParseError:
            pass
            # Show an error page

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        usernames = [user.email for user in models.User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)

    def post(self, request):
        usernames = [user.email for user in models.User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)
```